# Closing window when object reaches bottom

Tags: python-3.6, zelle-graphics

I want to display a message, and close the window when the user clicks. This should happen when the circle reaches the bottom of the window. I'm not sure how to go about this, everything works fine until the circle passes the bottom of the window, the closing message doesn't pop up and the window doesnt close on click. I'm using the graphics.py graphics library from Zelle for Python. I'm a beginner in Python so my knowledge is very limited right now. My code is as follows:

```
from graphics import *

    def q2a():
        win = GraphWin("window",400,400)
        win.setCoords(0,0,400,400)
        win.setBackground("light grey")
        #drawing circle
        circle = Circle(Point(200,100),30)
        circle.setFill("red")
        circle.draw(win)
        #text
        message = Text(Point(200,200),"Click Anywhere to Begin")
        message.draw(win)
        #clicking
        while True:
            click = win.checkMouse()
            if click:
                message.undraw()
                while circle.getCenter().getY() < 170:
                    dy=1
                    dx = 0
                    dy *=-.01
                    circle.move(dx,dy)
        if circle.getCenter()== 0:
            circle.undraw()
            gameover = Text(Point(200,200),"Game Over - Click to Close")
            gameover.draw(win)
            win.checkMouse()
            win.close()


        q2a()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is simpler than you're making it.  One problem is that this is an infinite loop:

```
while circle.getCenter().getY() < 170:
    dy=1
    dx = 0
    dy *=-.01
    circle.move(dx,dy)
```

As circle's Y center starts at 100 and decreases, so it's always less than 170 so this loop never finishes and any code beyond this point is never executed.  Let's use the circle's radius, 30, instead so the circle stops when it sits on the bottom of the window.

Another issue is that I believe you're using `checkMouse()` when you really want `getMouse()`.  Read the documentation about the difference between these two commands.

Here's my rework of your code (with some style tweaks.)  I changed the -0.01 increment to -0.1 as I've no patience!

```
from graphics import *

RADIUS = 30
HEIGHT, WIDTH = 400, 400
CENTER = Point(HEIGHT / 2, WIDTH / 2)

def q2a():
    win = GraphWin("window", HEIGHT, WIDTH)
    win.setCoords(0, 0, HEIGHT, WIDTH)
    win.setBackground("light grey")

    # drawing circle
    circle = Circle(Point(WIDTH / 2, 100), RADIUS)
    circle.setFill("red")
    circle.draw(win)

    # text
    message = Text(CENTER, "Click Anywhere to Begin")
    message.draw(win)

    # moving
    win.getMouse()
    message.undraw()

    while circle.getCenter().getY() > RADIUS:
        circle.move(0, -0.1)

    # end game
    circle.undraw()
    gameover = Text(CENTER, "Game Over - Click to Close")
    gameover.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

q2a()
```